# Solving Riccati differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I was unable to solve the following differential equation.
We've just started, so the level can't be so huge, however i didn't find an appropriate method for this one in particular.

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = x(y^2) + x^5$$

i found that,according to wolframalpha, this equation is called Riccati differential equation.
There is a relatively simple way to solve it?

Comment: the solution containes the Bessel function

Comment: It feels like $z=x^2$ so $dy/dz=(y^2+z^2)/2$ might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $y=\frac{p}{q}$, 
$$
\frac{p'}q-\frac{pq'}{q^2}=\frac{dy}{dx}=x\frac{p^2}{q^2}+x^5
$$

which suggests $$q'=-xp$$ so that $$p'=x^5q$$ remains, which is now a system of 2 linear ODE, or in combination
$$
q''=-x(x^5q)-p\implies xq''-q'+x^7q=0
$$ 
with the corresponding solution theory, power series expansion, numerical methods,...

Setting $q=xf(x^4/4)$ following the solution form of [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27(x)%3Dxy(x)%5E2%2Bx%5E5) gives $$q'=x^4f'(x^4/4)+f(x^4/4),\\ xq''=x^8f''(x^4/4)+5x^4f'(x^4/4)$$ so that insertion results in
$$
x^8f''(x^4/4)+5x^4f'(x^4/4)-x^4f'(x^4/4)-f(x^4/4)+x^8f(x^4/4)=0
$$
and with $4t=x^4$
$$
t^2f''(t)+tf'(t)+\Bigl(t^2-\frac1{16}\Bigr)f(t)=0
$$
which is the equation of a Bessel function.